# Is there anyway to input a command upon the first player joining and the last player leaving my Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-forge

We're running a modded server with Serene Seasons and I'd like to toggle the season cycle gamerule whenever players are online then again when everyone is offline. I don't seem to have any automated tasks features on my server dashboard so I'm wondering how I might do so with Command Blocks or if there are any alternative options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simple

If you don't care about it running on every tick, this is the simpliest solution:

```
/execute if entity @a[limit=1] run gamerule DoSeasonsCycle true
/execute unless entity @a[limit=1] run gamerule DoSeasonsCycle false
```

The only reason I'm giving a more complex afterwards is that I'm not sure if this would flood the server logs

---

#### A bit extra

But if you want to run it a single time, and not use datapacks:

##### Summary answer:

Run in your chat once:

```
/scoreboard objectives add AnyPlayer dummy
/scoreboard players set $State AnyPlayer 0
```

In loop:

```
/execute if score $State AnyPlayer matches 0 if entity @a[limit=1] run gamerule DoSeasonsCycle true
/execute if score $State AnyPlayer matches 0 if entity @a[limit=1] run scoreboard players set $State AnyPlayer 1

/execute if score $State AnyPlayer matches 1 unless entity @a[limit=1] run gamerule DoSeasonsCycle false
/execute if score $State AnyPlayer matches 1 unless entity @a[limit=1] run scoreboard players set $State AnyPlayer 0
```

#### Explanation

We need a scoreboard to track the states:

- 0: No players
- If 0 and there is a player: Someone just joined
- 1: At least one player
- If 1 and there is no player: Last person left

Create the scoreboard and set its inital state to 0:

```
/scoreboard objectives add AnyPlayer dummy
/scoreboard players set $State AnyPlayer 0
```

The idea is, if you don't have players and the score is set to 1 (which means there were), run the commands followed by setting the score to 0. The opposite idea applies.

If players left:

```
/execute if score $State AnyPlayer matches 1 unless entity @a[limit=1] run (your gamerule command here, set to false)
/execute if score $State AnyPlayer matches 1 unless entity @a[limit=1] run scoreboard players set $State AnyPlayer 0
```

Once a player joins:

```
/execute if score $State AnyPlayer matches 0 if entity @a[limit=1] run (your gamerule command here, set to true)
/execute if score $State AnyPlayer matches 0 if entity @a[limit=1] run scoreboard players set $State AnyPlayer 1
```